# Blender 2.82 subdivision problem

Tags: modifiers, transforms

blender newbie here. I want to subdivide a plate but encountered a problem. This is the object(circle:ngon filled) before the subdivision.

[image]

This is after. the frame becomes blurry in edit mode.
[image]

Attempts to transform alters the object irrationally. I moved the innermost loop in the z-axis and here's what happened.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Someone help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the mesh visibility, it's normal you can't see some vertices as you've given your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. This modifier slightly deforms your surface, but the vertices are still displayed at their original position, so they might be hidden by the surface deformations. If you want the vertices to stick to the position that they will have once the modifier is applied, enable the modifier's *On Cage* option:

[image]

The other problem you're probably talking about is the fact that your vertices stick to the surface as soon as you're moving them, and that's because you've enabled the *Snapping* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's all fixed

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, your model's mesh may appear inconsistent or cause bugs when you add an additional modeling step.

One of the solutions consists in making disappear the vertices which make duplicates. To do this in Edit Mode, press [A] to select all points of the object. Then press [M] and select "By Distance".

If this doesn't work, other solutions are well explained in this article:

[blendamator.com/the-7-most-common-mistakes-in-blender/](https://blendamator.com/les-7-erreurs-les-plus-courantes-dans-blender/)